# Conditions in msbuild-extension (or regex)?

Tags: .net-3.5, tfs, msbuild, msbuild-task

Is there any way to put conditions in MSBuild-extension? More specifically, I need to replace some string in config file (using `<File.Replace />`), which may look like '/service.svc' '{some characters here}/service.svc'. How can you make it, using conditions or regexp?

P.S. I'm yet to determine version that is used, but believe it to be for .net 3.5, as this framework version is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation. I'm using one mapping file for multiple environments. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.

You can call it from MSBuild script using Exec task.

Comment: Well, editing mapping file by Excel isn't seen as an advantage by me, but thanks for the link anyway.